# SWIG %import works with python2 but doesn't work as expected with python3

Tags: python-3.x, swig

I want to convert a big SWIG project to work with modules.
module1 contains types definitions
module2 and module3 contain APIs that use definitions from module1

---

```
// File module2.i 
%module module2
%{
#include "module1.h"
%}

%import "module1.i"

%include "module2.h"`
```

---

```
// File module3.i 
%module module3
%{
#include "module1.h"
%}

%import "module1.i"

%include "module3.h"
```

---

I also have a package Test

```
Test
 |- module1
 |- module2
 |- module3
```

The generated python modules module2.py and module3.py contain the following import :
*import module1*

The generated code works on python2 but doesn't work on python3 because import require also name of package. Something like :
from Test.module1 import *

So I get an error :
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module1'

I am trying to find how to make this work with python3.
Any help would be appreciated. You can ask me for more details if you want.

I tried to find some relation to python3 in SWIG doc but didn't find something relevant.

Comment: You need to different C runtimes, one for Python2 and one for Python3 and generate two `.pyd` files. The easiest approach is to use `CMake` for finding both Python2 and Python3 and the different libraries needed for linking